# Go + Protocol buffers acting really strange

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I'm writing a service-based server for a project I'm working on, which is written in Go and uses Protocol Buffers for inter-service communication. Everything was working fine until I added protocols named `DeviceRequest` and `DeviceResponse`, now the compiler can't find them, while the go source of the protocol exists and is set up in my `GOPATH`. WebStorm also finds them, but for some reason the compiler doesn't. The strange thing is that old protocols of which the Go source doesn't exist anymore do work (Webstorm also does not recognize them), see these screenshots [image] [image] [image]

I've tried deleting the files in my `GOPATH`, but that didn't work. My guess is that `go` is using some kind of cache memory but I couldn't find anything about that online.

Comment: Plese [edit] you question and include code, not screenshots.

Comment: are you aware of Cmd+Shift+4?  full screenshots aren't necessary. we can't zoom in!

Comment: @sircapsalot I'll zoom in, I wasn't aware of the fact that you can't zoom in on this

Comment: @LutzHorn Code isn't quite useful here, the screenshots are only to demonstrate that my IDE acts like I'd expect, but `go` doesn't

Comment: @Dirk: This may sound harsh, but nobody is interested in your IDE. Only the output  of your compiler matters.

Comment: @Volker I know, but the compiler doesn't say anything either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Protocol buffers are not compiled automatically into Go code unless you have a third party tool that does this. The protoc tool that is part of Protocol Buffers would be used to create the Go implementation of the .proto files. The output should reside in your $GOPATH/src. The .a files would be stored under $GOPATH/pkg. The code completion looks at the $GOPATH/pkg whereas the "go" tool would look in $GOPATH/src for anything that had changed.

Remove the contents of $GOPATH/pkg and then run "go install" to recreate the .a files.

Comment: That did it, but I'm curious; is there any reason `protoc-gen-go` would update the .go files, but not the object files?

Comment: protoc is only responsible for creating the .go files. The object files are created by the normal go compilation.